# How to update data from child class variables using parent class function?

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm trying to practise my c# by doing a little exercise creating a basic ORM.

So i have 3 files, my Main program calling my Model:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Pessoa mPessoa = new Pessoa();

        mPessoa.First();

        MessageBox.Show(mPessoa.nome);
    }
```

My child model class:

```
class Pessoa:Model
{
    public int id;
    public string nome;
    public string telefone;

    public Pessoa()
    {
        Table = "Pessoa";
        Conn = "Principal";
    }
}
```

And my parent Model Class:

```
class Model:Conn
{

    protected string Table;
    protected string Conn;

    public void First()
    {
        OpenConnection();

        string query = "SELECT * from " + Table + " Where id = 1 limit 1";

        DataTable oDT = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

        da.Fill(oDT);

        foreach (var column in oDT.Columns)
        {


       }

    }
```

The question is: How can i update the child class variables (id, nome and telefone) based on the results from my parent class funcion?

As you can see, i've tried to use dynamic variable names using that foreach with the columns from the result, but i'm stuck because i dont know how to properly set the values.

Comment: I suppose the method `first` in your parent class `Model` is to be used as a generic, if so. It would be better if you make the method `First` in your `Model` class as *protected* and access it from your child class instead of doing the reverse because children can have a different implementation of it(*if I guessed it right*). And let it return the `DataTable` *oDT* which can be modified in the child method.

Comment: Try following : DataRow[] rows = oDT.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
foreach(Data row in rows)
{
   row["Conn"] = "My Connection";
}